# My MATLAB launcher doesn't work

Tags: launcher, matlab

I've installed MATLAB R2011a on Ubuntu 11.10 today following [Ubuntu's guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB).

I've also followed the steps to create the launcher. It appeared, but when I click on it nothing happens. Does anyone knows what can I do to fix it?

#### Additional info

I can run it perfectly through terminal. My only problem is getting the launcher to work.
To create the launcher I used [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB#Create_A_MATLAB_Launcher):

> 1. Get an icon:
>
>    ```
>     sudo wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Matlab_Logo.png -O /usr/share/icons/matlab.png
>    ```
> 2. Get the launcher file:
>
>    ```
>     sudo wget 'https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=matlab-r2011a.desktop' -O /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
>    ```

Comment: How did you create the launcher? Also can you confirm that you can launch matlab from a terminal?

Comment: I can run it perfectly trough terminal. My only problem is getting the launcher to work.
To create the launcher I used the instructions on <https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB#Create_A_MATLAB_Launcher>     I added the info you requested on the original message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try specifying the full path in the launcher you are using.

So for example if the output of `which matlab` is `/usr/bin/matlab`, then change
the `Exec` field to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/matlab -desktop
```

Note that if this *does* solve the issue for you it's likely because you have a script called `matlab` that is shadowing the original `matlab` command and so perhaps `matlab` is not receiving the `-desktop` flag which it needs to run when launched without a terminal.

See [this entry](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20) for more details about getting the launcher to start properly by using `-desktop`.

If for some reason you still get nothing, try setting the `type` field to terminal application to diagnose the problem further.

Comment: I went to /usr/share/applications, right clicket on matlab and tried to change the execute command, without success. Everytime I closed it it returned to the defauld. Is there any way to do it using the terminal?

Comment: @Daniel: you need to do it as root. You can do this eg, using `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop` from a terminal (or using whatever other text editor you prefer)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and many of the fixes I found didn't work. Here was the solution I finally came to using Ubuntu 14.04 with MATLAB 2016a.

MATLAB opens from the terminal fine, so find out what is being called for that command:

```
> which matlab
/usr/local/bin/matlab
```

Then to actually create the icon, I just launched MATLAB from the terminal

```
> matlab
```

and when the icon appeared in the launcher, I right clicked on it and clicked 'Lock to Launcher'. Here is where my solution diverged from a lot of the other solutions. Instead creating a .desktop file in `/usr/local/applications`, I actually had to modify the one that was created in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
> gedit ~/.local/share/applications/matlab_r2016a.desktop
```

and modified the file to

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MATLAB R2016a
Icon=matlab_r2016a.png
Path=/home/username
Exec=/usr/local/bin/matlab -desktop
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=MATLAB R2016a
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

where the Path points to your home directory and the Exec is whatever `which matlab` returned plus the flag `-desktop`

Comment: I'll note that I'm still having problems with the launcher-based MATLAB, though. It does not recognize environment variables from `.bashrc`, where is a MATLAB session launched from a terminal does

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to get the command described in Exec tag, inside /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop file, or equivalent, and try it on the command line. It probably will show an error message!

I found a message like:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
`GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/glnxa64/libCppMicroServices.so.3.1.1)
```

You can try to update the libraries with the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9
sudo apt-get upgrade libstdc++6
```

After that try again!
Source:[MATLAB displaying erroneous message during launching](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/389024-why-does-matlab-r2018a-display-erroneous-message-on-ubuntu-16-04)