# Unable to launch MATLAB via icon

Tags: 16.04, matlab

I have MATLAB 2016a installed on Ubuntu 16.4. I can launch MATLAB from the command line but I am unable to successfully launch it from the icon in 'Search' or if I try to create a shortcut. Does anyone have a solution that will allow me to create a working shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
```

Then type ls in order to see a list of files in that directory. Based on your version of MATLAB, you will see a file with .desktop extension. For me, its name is matlab_r2015a_-_academic_use.desktop.

Try to open it by:

```
gedit matlab_r2015a_-_academic_use.desktop
```

Then locate a line that starts with Exec. Write -desktop at the end of that line. The result will be something similar to:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/matlab -desktop
```

Save and close the opened file. Your launcher icon should work now.

My answer is derived from the following link:
[My MATLAB launcher doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172039/my-matlab-launcher-doesnt-work)

It might be helpful to look at it, too.